# Angular-chosen: selected value not displayed immediately

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-chosen

I'm using `angular-chosen` in my angular application. I have in a modal, different inputs and a `select chosen`. The modal let the user add or edit person's informations. My problem is that in the edit mode, the selected value of the `chosen` is not displayed at the first time. It's just when I reopen the modal that I can see the selected value. I verified if the data takes too much time to be loaded, but it seems like it's a problem with the chosen and the modal. 
This is how I display it:

```
 <select id="school" name="school" 
   no-results-text="'No data'" chosen
     disable-search-threshold="1" ng-model="person.school"
     ng-options="school as school.name + ' - ' + school.districtName + ' - ' + school.regionName  + ' - ' + school.cityName  for school in schools track by school.id">
          <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
   </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to start it from the controller because ng-model is **undefined** and no **''** or the value you want to choose
    `person.school = ''`
or maybe in a `ng-init="person.school = ''"` in the select tag